# Azure AD B2C: Invalid Request: AADB2C90012: The scope 'openid profile offline_access' provided in request is not supported

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an Angular application that uses MSAL to authenticate with Azure AD B2C. Everything was working fine until suddenly we started getting an error

> ServerError: invalid_request: AADB2C90012: The scope 'openid profile offline_access' provided in request is not supported.

I do have a custom scope ("read") which I have removed from the list to see if that was the issue (not passing that through should only affect the access token that is returned after authentication)

I have tried clearing the cache on my browser to no effect. As far as I can tell, nothing has changed in the configuration of our Azure AD B2C tenant. I even tried deleting an re-creating the app registration.

The only potential thing that could have affected it is that I tried to create and apply a conditional access policy which I subsequently deleted. There is a possibility that something is cached, but its been almost 24 hours now.

Has anyone experience this before? Any suggestions of what I can try? The next thing I can think of is to create a new Azure AD B2C tenant (this tenant is used for Dev & QA)

Comment: I finally found the issue. I hadn't thought to check my package-lock.json file and so missed the fact that the version of the MSAL packages had been updated. I was using version 3.0.0-beta.1 of the @azure/msal-angular and @azure/msal-browser packages and didn't notice they had updated to the newly released V3.0.1 which was causing the issue. Looks like I'm not the only one experiencing this pain: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/6355.

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Hashitha it seems to be a problem with the latest version of the package (V3.0.1). As per my comment above, I rolled back to the previous beta package (3.0.0-beta.1)